# How to add favicon for mkdocs websites?

Tags: favicon, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I am developing mkdocs website. Here I need to add favicon for my website. I tried like this but it is not working.

I added site_favicon in mkdocs.yaml file and using readthedocs theme. But it is not working

```
site_favicon: img/favicon.ico
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply save your new image to `img/favicon.ico` within your `docs_dir`. There is no need to change any setting.

Back in version 0.16.0, the `site_favicon` configuration setting was deprecated. Then in version 0.17.0 is was completely removed. Therefore, your config is doing nothing.

All of that said, you may be running into the bug reported at [#1671](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1671), which was fixed in [#1672](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1672) and will be available in the next release. If so, you will need to wait until 1.1 is released.